# What is $\binom{a}b$ with $a<b$?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

@Chris's_sis gave me following hint in a problem :

$\frac{1}{ \displaystyle  \binom{ p+k}{p}}- \frac{1}{ \displaystyle\binom{p+k+1}{p}} =\frac{ p}{p+1}\frac{ 1}{\displaystyle\binom{p-k-1}{p-1}}$

However, in $\binom{p-k-1}{p-1}$ we have $p-k-1<p-1$

What is $\binom{a}b$ when $a<b$ ? Do we use $\Gamma$ and compute negative factorials ?

Comment: It's generalization of binomial coefficient, look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of ${a\choose b}$ is $0$ if $a<b$ and $a,b$ are both integers. There are two reasons for this, coming from two definitions of ${n\choose k}$

1. On one hand, ${a\choose b}$ is defined as "the number of $b$-sized subsets of a $a$-sized subset." Of course, a set with $a$ elements has no subsets of $b>a$ elements, so, by this definition, ${a\choose b} = 0.$
2. If you want to ignore the combinatorial definitions of ${a\choose b}$, you can simply define $${a\choose b} = \frac{a\cdot (a-1)\cdots (a-b+1)}{b!},$$
   and, since $a-b+1 \leq 0$ and $a>0$, this means that one of the numbers $a,a-1,\dots, a-b+1$ must be zero, causing the whole product to equal zero.

Comment: Then $\binom{p-k-1}{p-1} = 0$  ? $(k>0)$

Comment: Yes. By both definitions.

Comment: Then $\frac{1}{ \displaystyle  \binom{ p+k}{p}}- \frac{1}{ \displaystyle\binom{p+k+1}{p}} =\frac{ p}{p+1}\frac{ 1}{\displaystyle\binom{p-k-1}{p-1}}$ would make no sense, would it ?

Comment: I agree completely.

Answer (score 2):

Just expand the binomial coefficient: $\binom{\alpha}{k} = \alpha (\alpha-1)
\ldots (\alpha -k +1)\cdot \frac{1}{k!}$. If $0< \alpha <k$, it's always 0.

Comment: Then shouldn't $\binom{p-k-1}{p-1}=0$ ?

Comment: is $p-k-1<0$? or positive?

Comment: if it's negative, you'll get something like $(-1)^k \phi(p)$

Comment: Try $\binom{-1}{k}$ for example, what do you get?

Comment: Not necessarily i believe (look at the 'hint' in the OP) - what is $\phi$ ?